# Preventing concatenation

Tags: javascript

I've been writing JavaScript on and off for 13 years, but I sort of rediscovered it in the past few months as a way of writing programs that can be used by anyone visiting a web page without installing anything.  See for [example](http://ab1jx.webs.com/calcs/calcs.html).

The showstopper I've recently discovered is that because JavaScript is loosely typed by design, it keeps concatenating strings when I want it to add numbers. And it's unpredictable.  One routine worked fine for several days then when I fed different data into it the problem hit and I ended up with an impossibly big number.

Sometimes I've had luck preventing this by putting `( )` around one term, sometimes I've had to resort to `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` on one term. It reminds me a little of trying to force a float result in C by putting a .00 on one (constant) term. I just had it happen when trying to `+=` something from an array that I was already loading by doing `parseFloat()` on everything.

Does this only happen in addition? If I use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` on at least one of the terms each time I add, will that prevent it?  I'm using Firefox 6 under Linux to write with, but portability across browsers is also a concern.

Answer (score 9):

[The specification says about the addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition):

> If Type(*lprim*) is String or Type(*rprim*) is String, then
> Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(*lprim*) followed by ToString(*rprim*)

Which means that if at least one operator is a string, string concatenation will take place.

> If I use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` on at least one of the terms each time I add, will that prevent it?

No, all operands have to be numbers.

You can easily convert any numerical string into a number using the [*unary plus* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) (it won't change the value if you are already dealing with a number):

```
var c = +a + +b;
```

Answer (score 8):

I normally do this:

```
var x = 2;
var t = "12";
var q = t+x; // q == "122"
var w = t*1+x; // *1 forces conversion to number w == 14
```

If t isn't a number then you'll get `NaN`.

If you multiply by 1 variables you don't know what type they are. They will be converted to a number. I find this method better than doing int and float casts, because *1 works with every kind of numbers.

The problem you are having is that the functions which fetch values from the DOM normally return strings. And even if it is a number it will be represented as a string when you fetch it.

Comment: Use `(t*1||0)` for multiple additions, where invalid values for `t` should be ignored: `NaN || 0` = 0, and `14 || 0` = 14.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `+` operator to convert a string to number.

```
var x = '111'
+x === 111
```

Answer (score 1):

Rest assured it is very predictable, you just need to be familiar with the operators and the data types of your input.

In short, evaluation is left-to-right, and concatenation will occur whenever in the presence of a string, no matter what side of the operation.

So for example:

```
9 + 9 // 18
9 + '9' // '99'
'9' + 9 // '99'
+ '9' + 9 // 18 - unary plus
- '9' + 9 // 0 - unary minus
```

Some ternary expressions:

```
9 + '9' + 9 // '999'
9 + 9 + '9' // '189'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember the left-right thing. I was mostly having trouble with variables, not constants, but it sounds like (1 * A) + B might work too.  I love reverse-engineering conveniences.  Page saved for later.  Alan

Comment: @ab1jx, not much difference between variables and constants. They evaluate in identical manners, and all the same rules apply. The tricks mentioned work, however I feel they're unnecessary in actual code. There should be a validation section that is separate from the calculations section, for purposes of maintenance and clarity (seeing `1*A + B` looks weird). I would convert all values to the right types and only then use them. In any case, good luck!